# Purpose of routes.php in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just want to know the purpose of this on routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";  
$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";
```

Comment: Scaffolding was deprecated as of at least 1.7, and is removed in 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first take your through routing and then tell you about the meaning of those lines in `routes.php`.

You should start with [URI Routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/routing.html). In short, what you do with routes is that you map a certain `URI` with a `controller/method/parameter` statement.

### Examples

See the following examples taken from the user guide:

So, something like `example.com/journals` can be routed to the `blogs` controller.

```
$route['journals'] = "blogs";
```

Another good example is when you are building a product catalogue and you need `example.com/product/some_id` to be routed to a controller `catalog`:

```
$route['product/(:num)'] = "catalog/product_lookup_by_id/$1";
```

In the example above, `catalog` will be the controller, `product_lookup_by_id` will be the method and `$1` is the parameter which is picked up from the URI.

### Answer to your question

You have asked:

> I just want to know the purpose of this on routes.php
>
> ```
> $route['default_controller'] = "welcome";  
> $route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";
> ```

The `default_controller` is quite obvious. This means `welcome/index` will be loading whenever `` `example.com/index `` is being requested.

`scaffolding_trigger` was deprecated in 1.7 but you can [read about it](http://cimple.org/user_guide/general/scaffolding.html). Scaffolding was a method which you could use to seed data in your database.

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
```

This is the default controller which codeigniter would start with when you didnt specify a controller to the URL.

**url:**

> ip/monitor/index.php

This will trigger the default controller aka welcome.php

**url:**

> ip/monitor/index.php/controller

This will, however, trigger your given controller and not the default one

This is mostly used to asign a *index page* as the start page.

---

I'm not sure about `$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";` as i never used it. But according to the comments it has been removed in version 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Routing rules are defined in your application/config/routes.php file. In it you'll see an array called $route that permits you to specify your own routing criteria. Routes can either be specified using wildcards or Regular Expressions.

For more detail please see this link :

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/routing.html